# Selenium Webdriver - Fetching column from a data table using Java 8

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to grab a column from a data table. 
Here is my table to use as an example, what I am looking for is to extract the Firstname from the table.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="abc">Jill</td>
    <td class="abc">Smith</td> 
    <td class="abc">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="abc">Eve</td>
    <td class="abc">Jackson</td> 
    <td class="abc">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can i modify the code below to give me this result:

```
Jill
Eve 


WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("searchResultsGrid"));

// Now get all the TR elements from the table
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
// And iterate over them, getting the cells
for (WebElement row : allRows) {
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for (WebElement cell : cells) {
        System.out.println("content >>   " + cell.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Java 8` you can iterate list using [`.forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) after getting only `Firstname` column list as below :-

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("searchResultsGrid"));

List<WebElement> firstCells = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr/td[1]"));
firstCells.forEach(firstCell->System.out.println("Firstname >>   " + firstCell.getText()));
```

Comment: I had div ID that I used to get to the table I want, class is bad practice to use and I took it from there. I start reading about how to build custom xpath which made my life a lot easier. Thanks for your input as always.